# Using janitor in R and I don't understand the error message from the janitor package

Tags: r, janitor

I have used the following R code:

```
janitor::tabyl(data, do_you_recycle,recycle_beauty_products)%>%
janitor::adorn_totals(where = c('row','col'))%>%  
janitor::adorn_percentages(denominator = "all")%>%
janitor::adorn_pct_formatting()
```

It worked last time I ran the code. However, I just reran it and got the following error:

```
Error in vectbl_assign(x[[j]], i, recycled_value[[j]]) :  DLL requires the use of native symbols
```

Could someone suggest how to change the code so it runs correctly?

Comment: are you using the latest versions? https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/1536

Comment: how do i update it?

Comment: Run `install.packages("janitor")` to update your version. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: i am now getting the following error Error in janitor::tabyl(data, Identify, Age) %>% janitor::adorn_totals(where = c("row",  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using ***tibble>=3.2.0***. You can install the latest version by `intall.packages('tibble')`